# How to add CLion icon to desktop in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, desktop, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am using Ubuntu and CLion 2016.1.

I installed it by downloading `tar.gz` archive.

Now I have such `CLion-2016.1/bin` folder. For launching Clion I run `./clion.sh`.

How can I add CLion icon to desctop?

[image]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can add a desktop entry to your system directly in CLion :

**Main Menu > Tools > Create Desktop entry...**

Comment: There is nothing like this in tools section in clion 2020.2. I see only create command line launcher. When I click that it says "Launcher script creation is now managed in Toolbox App settings. See the Toolbox App announcement for more details". Can you help me out?

Comment: CLion 2021.3.3 - works fine. Anyone who is interested can find it in the Tool section at the top bar.

Comment: On Ubuntu, after you do this step, use "Show Applications", launch it, and then right-click and pick "Add to Favorites".

Answer (score 8):

Download the file [clion.desktop](https://github.com/pld-linux/clion/blob/master/clion.desktop), put it in `~/.local/share/applications` and mark it executable. You may need to adapt the `Icon` and `Exec` path to point to `CLion-2016.1/bin/clion.svg` and resp. `CLion-2016.1/bin/clion.sh`.

This will allow the launcher etc. to find clion, you can also copy the file to `~/Desktop` to have it on your desktop.

Comment: ./clion.desctop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
./clion.desctop: line 6: fg: no job control
./clion.desctop: line 7: with: command not found
./clion.desctop: line 8: IDE: command not found

Comment: I run ./clion.desctop

Answer (score 5):

After you're done with the installation as described in `Install-Linux-tar.txt`, you can create a desktop shortcut so that you can launch `CLion` easily using <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and then typing `CLion` (need not be case-sensitive).

#### Creating Desktop Entry:

`cd` to your CLion installation directory; I use `/usr/share/clion-2020.1.1`; Then do:

```
$ bash bin/clion.sh
```

That will launch `CLion` window. At the bottom right of the window, there's `configure`, click that and then click `Create Desktop Entry`. That's it!

Now, you'll be able to search using the term `clion` after pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

---

Tested on **Ubuntu 19.10** and **CLion 2020**

Answer (score 1):

From CLion welcome window select:

1. customize
2. All settings
3. Appearance & Behavior
4. Menus and Toolbars
5. Main Menu -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...

(if you don't have 'Create...' action available, you can add it using the button "Add Action" on the right side of the search bar)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there is no **Tools > Create Desktop entry** option in the manual, you can create your own desktop icon easily.

1. Create a new file called "clion.desktop" in your desktop folder
2. Type the following in it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=CLion
Icon=path-to/clion.png
Exec=path-to/clion.sh
```

You can find the corresponding path by:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "clion.sh"
sudo find / -type f -name "clion.png"
```

3. Make "clion.desktop" an executable.

```
chmod +x clion.desktop
```

Then you should be able to open clion by double-click it in your desktop.